# Kendo MVC Grid date time object format when using in built functions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have question regarding the Create & Update functions handling datetime objects.

My environment's set up to use the dd/mm/yyyy format for datetime, but when any of the Kendo MVC Grid's in built functions are called, the dates are sent over in the mm/dd/yyyy format which causes my model to become invalid (e.g. a date like today 6/1/2015 works (even though it's wrong) as it thinks its 6th January - when it should be 1st June, the program breaking problem occurs when the date has a value such as 5/13/2015 - as there isn't a 13th month).

What is the correct way of telling the Kendo MVC grid that it should be using dd/mm/yyyy format when it handles datetime objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that the easiest way to fix this issue is to assign the culture that you want from telerik.

I was able to get the datetime format i needed by following the guide from the official telerik website here.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/globalization#use-the-same-culture-on-the-server-and-client-side